# История консоли в pycharm

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm, история

Всем привет. На днях написал программу, которая должна выводить в консоль(run) историю сообщений в вк. Запустил, через какое-то время запустил другую программу, а историю сохранить забыл. Вот вопрос: можно ли как-то посмотреть то, что было выведено в предыдущих запусках программ в pycharm?[image: пример того, что я подразумеваю под словом "консоль"( место, куда вывелось hello)]

Comment: возможно я вас не очень хорошо понял, но вы пробовали в терминале команду history

Answer (score -1):

Посмотри в контекстном меню "VSC" -> "Local History"